# Chromcast instream subtitles are not working

Tags: chromecast

I am trying to play video with multiple instream subtitles on Chromecast custom receiver application, but it not working. Here is the code that I use for enabling subtitles stream:

```js
mediaElement.addEventListener('playing', function(e) {
  setStreamLanguage('text', 'fin');
  player.enableCaptions(true);
});

function setStreamLanguage(streamType, languageCode){
            var streamInfo;
            var streamToEnable = -1;

            for(var i = 0; i < protocol.getStreamCount(); ++i) {
                streamInfo = protocol.getStreamInfo(i);

                if (streamInfo.mimeType.indexOf(streamType) == 0) {
                    // select first stream by default in case there are no passed stream
                    if (streamToEnable < 0)
                        streamToEnable = i;

                    // disable all stream
                    protocol.enableStream(i, false);

                    // find a stream to enable
                    if (streamInfo.language == languageCode)
                        streamToEnable = i;

                    console.log('cycling throught: ' + streamInfo.mimeType + " " + streamInfo.language + " " +
                                "is selected: " + protocol.isStreamEnabled(i));
                }
            }

            if (streamToEnable >= 0)
            {
                protocol.enableStream(streamToEnable, true);
                console.log("stream " + streamToEnable + " is enabled now");
            }
        }
```

As a result video is being played, but no subtitles are displayed. Also there is an error in console: "Uncaught URIError: URI malformed".

Here is the manifest, used for test: http://usp.neonstingray.com/video/13440/13440.ism/Manifest.

Here is chromecast receiver logs: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e992c306602fb3cb5b8a

Comment: To debug your issue, we need to have a sample stream (with no DRM) that can exhibit the problem. Would you be able to provide such sample stream? If so, and if you don't want to share that publicly, please open a ticket here (https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?hl=en&rd=1) and provide a reference to this conversation, a sample stream with no DRM and have that routed to me so we can see what is happening, thanks.

Comment: Hello, finally I found a problem - we have encrypted subtitles in our manifest. But I can use external subtitles and it works fine, so will go with that solution. Thank you!